# freebase MQL query to match any field

Tags: java, freebase, mql

My application gets in input a certain amount of String, suppose the name of the "object" I'm looking for, and other fields like the year when an artist was born or the last album he made.

By the way the application has no knowledge on the type of the object in input, so what I'm trying to do is making an MQL query that, given the name of the object and other values (in any field, as I don't know the type of what I'm querying), returns me the type of what I searched. Once I get its type, I could for example make a better query asking for specifical fields.

As we all know, an example is worth thousand words, so let's assume my input is "The Police" and "So Lonely", one of their songs. I just know "The Police" is the name of what I'm looking for, but I don't know nothing about "So Lonely", so I should insert it someway in the query to get better results, without the knowledge of its type.

My first basic query is:

```
[{
"name": "The Police",
"type": []
}]
```

and it works, but I can't refine my search including so lonely, that could narrow the search output.

Any hint?

Comment: still couldn't solve it!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I need to accomplish, once I do the above (and still no idea on how to do it!) would be printing a summary of the entity i found. For example above, I would not have ALL the information about "The Police", but only basic general fields, that could be albums, the year they were born.

Is this possible to do something like that without the knowledge of what I found?